# Write a function named shortest() that finds the length of the shortest string in a list of strings

Tags: python, string

Write a function named `shortest()` that finds the length of the shortest string in a list of strings.
The function `shortest()` takes one parameter:
1. a list of strings, textList
The function `shortest()` should return the length of the shortest string in textList. You may assume that textList contains at least one element (string).

For example, the following program would output `1`:

```
beatleLine = ['I', 'am', 'the', 'walrus']
print(shortest(beatleLine))
```

I have no idea where to go from here:

```
def shortest(textList):
  for element in textList:
    min(textList)
```

Comment: It is a practice midterm that I am trying to study for, though thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
def shortest(textList):
    shortest_string_len=len(textList.pop())
    for text in textList:
        actual_text_len=len(text)
        if actual_text_len < shortest_string_len:
            shortest_string_len=actual_text_len
    return (shortest_string_len)


beatleLine = ['I', 'am', 'the', 'walrus']
print(shortest(beatleLine))
```

Comment: Suggestion: First line of this function should validate that textList is not empty before calling `textList.pop()`

Comment: Also this is very scary since it actually mutates the list you pass it. I'd be very upset if I found a function re-implementing `min(x, key=len)` that mutated my list without documenting that fact!

Comment: @selbie: Well, the program specs do say you're allowed to assume the list isn't empty. Which is a bit slack, IMHO, but that's program specs for you. :) However, I _strongly_ agree with Adam that needlessly & silently mutating a function argument is evil.

Answer (score 3):

This is the most pythonic version:

```
def shortest_length(textlist):
    return min(len(i) for i in textlist)
```

though here a `map` is also beautiful:

```
def shortest_length(textList):
    return min(map(len, textlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy with lambdas:

```
shortest = lambda strings: len(min(strings, key = len))
```

Comment: Ashwini, all you did was change my little segue, you did nothing to change the code.

Comment: This answer is wrong, I think -- it returns (one of) the shortest strings, but the OP is looking for "the length of the shortest string".  Things like that happen if you're trying too fast..

Comment: Easy fix DSM. How about this?

Comment: Why would I change your code? And how is "I'm not here to do you homework" helpful to OP when you already solved their homework that too without any explanation.

Comment: @Frxstrem I don't really appreciate your sarcasm. I am a high schooler so I understand Timothy's situation. I decided to help giving a complete answer knowing full well it would be too complicated for him. Beginners don't know anything about lambdas or sort keys, I left that for him to research on his own and for him to involve himself with the code and to understand it. Stack Overflow isn't a one way street, I'm making him work for his answer. Again, I don't need your sarcasm.

Comment: He's not working for anything; you gave him a piece of code that he can copy-paste! If you want to leave something as an exercise for the reader, describe the necessary code in prose instead of writing it out.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: If Timothy hands in Malik's solution which uses Python features that the class is unlikely to have covered at this stage, I'm pretty sure that his teacher will be rather suspicious. However, such "joke" solutions to homework questions should probably be confined to comments rather than posting them as answers. IMO.